# How to install "blue dragon" server for coldfusion in mac

Tags: java, macos, coldfusion, installation, bluedragon

I want to install "blue dragon" server for cold fusion on mac machine. I have study the installation guide they have written that this server can installed on mac but they have not given the installaton intructions and method about installation on mac instead they have given the complete instructions about windows and linux installtion.

http://www.newatlanta.com/products/bluedragon/self_help/docs/7_1/BlueDragon_71_Server_JX_Installation_Guide.pdf

Can any one help me in this matter?

Comment: I don't believe BlueDragon is maintained any longer. I'm not sure but it looks like the last version 7.1.1 was released in 2011. If you are looking for a free CFML engine I would recommend [Lucee](http://lucee.org/) instead (previously known as Railo). The latest release is version 5.1.3.18 released on Mar 29, 2017. Lucee 5 is ready for production environments.

Comment: Unless you have a business-critical need to use Blue Dragon, I'd avoid it like the plague. Lucee is your only open source CFML option at this point. 

If you absolutely need to run in on a Mac, install VirtualBox with a VM of whichever Linux or Windows OS it supports and install it there.